# Error in development: Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I was about to add `index.png` in my views and got this error. I have put the file in `app/assets/images/index.png`

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in Maps#new

Showing /home/sumin/sumin/project/tourism-board/app/views/maps/new.html.slim where line #9 raised:

Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( index.png )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server

Extracted source (around line #33):
      url_for establishment.avatar.variant(resize: ' 10x10 ')
    else
      image_url 'index.png'
    end
  end
end

Rails.root: /home/sumin/sumin/project/tourism-board
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/helpers/application_helper.rb:33:in `establishment_marker_url'
app/views/maps/new.html.slim:9:in `block in _app_views_maps_new_html_slim___2128975323729843504_70193639517680'
app/views/maps/new.html.slim:7:in `map'
app/views/maps/new.html.slim:7:in `_app_views_maps_new_html_slim___2128975323729843504_70193639517680'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why but I solved this problem by changing the name of my asset from `index.png` to `marker.png`. I think it should not have been `index.png`. Something is interesting with the name `index`